# Check if Database exists MSSQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, uwp

I have code like this:

```
private bool CheckDatabase(string databaseName, bool bRet)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master";
        string cmdText = "select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=\'" + databaseName + "\'";



        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
            {
                int nRet = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // regMessage.Text = nRet.ToString();
                if (nRet <= 0)
                {
                    bRet = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    bRet = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return bRet;
    }
```

However

> nRet

results always -1, as if the database did not exist(It does).
Is it the problem because database is empty yet?
Or should it return >0 if database was created, even if it is empty?
the string databaseName is correct by the way.

EDIT>
EDIT:
I also get strage error on "CREATE DATABASE @database" ssql command:

> 'Incorrect syntax near '@userDatabase'

the code is like thiss:

```
    var connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security = SSPI; database = master";
                string cmdText = "CREATE DATABASE @userDatabase";
                using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@userDatabase", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databaseName;=
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery doesn't work with SELECT statements (or better it doesn't return anything from a select)

Comment: here is where I got the code from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30f62638-2707-42dc-bc8d-9304ed767d24/check-if-database-exists?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: Beware of little bobby tables.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for `ExecuteNonQuery` states: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."

Comment: So basically, you're doing a SELECT so `ExecuteNonQuery` will **always** return -1.

Comment: because there are no rows. correct?

Comment: No, because `ExecuteNonQuery` will **always** return -1 from anything that isn't UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. If your SELECT selected 1,000 rows, `ExecuteNonQuery` will still return -1.

Comment: I see. why they used it as a solution in post I showed above>

Comment: The solution in that post is bad. Don't trust everything you read on the internet!

Comment: Ok. thanks for the clarification

Comment: the guy on the forum appeared to be trustfull

Comment: Better look at upvoted answers on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: This is a different question now, it should have been posted as a new question. Anyway yoi can't parameterize identifiers in sql. Create database can't take a variable as the database name.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, I already did that. Already know it is not possible. I am changing the way I store data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use parameterized queries.
2. Use `Select count(*)` instead of `Select *`.
3. Use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`
4. Note the remarks on the code, they explain the changes I've made.

```
// No point of passing a bool if all you do is return it...
private bool CheckDatabase(string databaseName)
{
    // You know it's a string, use var
    var connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master";
    // Note: It's better to take the connection string from the config file.

    var cmdText = "select count(*) from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=@database";

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
        {
            // Use parameters to protect against Sql Injection
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@database", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databaseName;

            // Open the connection as late as possible
            sqlConnection.Open();
            // count(*) will always return an int, so it's safe to use Convert.ToInt32
            return Convert.ToInt32( sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and how do I check if database exists? I

Comment: should I close the connection afterwards?

Comment: `bool doesExists = CheckDatabase("My database");`, You don't need to close the connection since the `using` statement is disposing it, and it's `Dispose` is doing that for you.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: HEy, will the same work for check if table exists? what shoul be the query?

Comment: should I write @"parameterName" or "@parameterName" ??

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, It should be `"@parameterName"` though if I think I remember reading somewhere Ado.Net will add the `@` for you if you didn't specify it

Comment: Yes. I thought so. But I am getting error when running the query. I will update the question so you can see whats happening if you will find a moment

Comment: You should **not** use the part `;database=master` in your connection string, otherwise you will try to connect to this database (which you do not yet know if it already exists) and the result of your method will take longer (in case to fail)

Comment: @PaulEfford Actually, the master database is a system database and I suspect it will always exist. However, you should probably not use it directly in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't use [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) to return something from a SELECT statement, your link to that MSDN forum contains an incorrect answer (as you already experimented)

MSDN docs explains that ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the sql statement ONLY for UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries. To count the number of rows affected by a SELECT it should retrieve the results with a lot more work to do. This probably would be not performance wise.

So you can change your function to

```
private bool CheckDatabase(string databaseName)
{
    string connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master";
    string cmdText = @"if Exists(select 1 from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=@db) 
                       select 1 else select 0";
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@db", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databaseName;
            int nRet = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return (nRet > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have changed:

- The bool variable passed as parameter is not required
- The most performant way to check for db existance is through the IF
  EXIST statement
- The database name should be passed as a parameter not with string
  concatenation
- Don't call ExecuteNonQuery but just ExecuteScalar to get the simple
  scalar value returned by the IF EXIST(... condition...) SELECT 0/1 statements
- The return value could be simplified

Comment: I need to get the bool value outside the CheckDatabase method

Comment: _bool result = CheckDatabase("yourdatabasename");_

Comment: good point about the use of `exists`, though you could probably do `select case when exists.... then 1 else 0 end;`

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the database file is, you can use `File.Exists()`:

```
if (File.Exists(DatabaseFile))

{
 //DoSomething
}
```